# I want to get or set data to each cell of DataGridView based on combobox selection

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Please find my code , I need to know the relationship between combobox selection and datagridview. Basically if I set my area selection only those related to the Area shall be display not the whole database as I am getting now. Thanks.

```
        private void RTUModification_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Select cell where checkbox to be display
        Rectangle rect = this.rtumodDGV1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);   
        chkbox.Size = new Size(18, 18);

        //set position of header checkbox where to places
        rect.Offset(4, 2);
        chkbox.Location = rect.Location;

        chkbox.CheckedChanged += rtucheckBoxCheckChanged;

        //Add CheckBox control to datagridView
        this.rtumodDGV1.Controls.Add(chkbox);

        // Create new DataTable instance
        dtDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
        if (null == dtDataTable)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Insufficient memory.", "ERROR");
        }
        //load the datable and fill them with value
        strErrorMsg = Utilities.OpenSQLConnection(out m_SqlConn, true, false);   //load normal database
        if (false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(strErrorMsg))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(strErrorMsg, "SQL connection ERROR");
        }

        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = null;
        strSelectCmd = "SELECT Area_ID, StationId, SystemId, CCNumber, LineNumber, RTUNumber, SRTUNumber, Description, SDescription FROM RTU_ADDRESS";
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.Connection = m_SqlConn;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = strSelectCmd;
        sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
        strErrorMsg = Utilities.FillDataTable(m_SqlConn, strSelectCmd, dtDataTable);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strErrorMsg) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to retrieve information from database.", "ERROR");
            dtDataTable.Dispose();
            Utilities.CloseAndDisposeSQLConnection(m_SqlConn);
        }
        int iRetrievedNoOfRecords = dtDataTable.Rows.Count;
        if (iRetrievedNoOfRecords > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < iRetrievedNoOfRecords; i++)
                this.rtumodcomboBox.Items.Add((string)dtDataTable.Rows[i]["Area_ID"]);
        }
        strErrorMsg = Utilities.ExecuteSQLCommand(m_SqlConn, strSelectCmd);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strErrorMsg) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Error!Loading into RTU datagrid");
        }

        //load the datagridview header
        rtumodDGV1.DataSource = dtDataTable;         
    }
```

Comment: Just a guess, you have not added any where clause in your query . Don't you think you need to attach selected area in where clause.

Comment: Why my post was voted down?, Thanks Faheem

Comment: The select will able to display all field, if I put where, how will it link to my combobbox and datagridview?. Please write a code for me to understand more.

Comment: Without a where clause means that you will get all rows in table.No matter what you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the sample code that you might need.

```
  strSelectCmd = "SELECT Area_ID, StationId, SystemId, CCNumber, LineNumber, RTUNumber, SRTUNumber, Description, SDescription FROM RTU_ADDRESS where Area_ID="+cbxMyCombox.SelectedIndex;
```

other options other SelectedIndex could be SelectedItem or SelectedValue . Depending upon what you are using. Which is unclear right now.

Comment: Fantastic, you save my life